# How to make a tape measure for exact measurements?

Tags: modeling

I am making an instruction video for burn victims, so that I can make their made to measure recovery garments in the exact size. I have made my person model, but now I need to show the area where the tape measure should be placed, to take the exact measurement, circumference etc. how can I do this? could I make a tape measure or just a line maybe…does any one please have a suggestion. I am new at this and am just learning…. please help…thank you so much

Comment: so your question really is "how do I wrap a tape measure around a model"

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are really trying to achieve, perhaps with some reference images or videos? What you want to do seems feasible, but as it stands it is unclear exactly what you wish to achieve

Comment: Hi, it is an instruction video to show how to take measurements of a victim of a burn tragedy(wether it be through fire, oil etc.)  I find that people who take the measurements are very inexperienced and all the measurements are impossibly incorrect. I need them to send me accurate measurements so the patient can recover quickly. video should indicate where the tape measure be placed. I will make different videos for example, face, hand, leg etc. i have used manuel bastioni lab for the model, I just  need to create a line or tape measure to indicate where to measure. thank you so much x

Answer (score 1):

First, two assumptions. One is that I assume your person model is made in compliance with the usual norms as far as topology and geometry of the model. The other is that the "exact measurements" to which you refer to in the title of your question relates to the exact measurements made and communicated to you, and not necessarily to obtaining exact measurements in the model. That written, here's what I would do.

1. Make a duplicate of your person model and move it to a different layer.
2. Figure out where on the model you will need to show the measurements, likely including (but not limited to) the neck, the chest, the upper and lower arms, the waist, the hips, and upper and lower legs.
3. At each point where you have identified a location where you need a measurement, define a contrasting material to any that might already be present on your real person model, and make two loop cuts around the duplicate person model in that location. Space those two loop cuts you just made to be about an inch apart, or so (relative to the model), and assign the new material to the areas between the two loopcuts.
4. When all of the areas where you need measurements have been marked, in the material context button of the object properties window, in edit mode, choose "select" to select all of the loop cuts with the material you need, then in the select menu in the 3D viewport header, choose "inverse selection". Now delete everything from the duplicate model that is not a location of a measurement you need.
5. Switch the pivot point to "median point", and scale each of the locations of the tape up by about 2 percent, constraining the scale directions so as not to change the scale of the tape in the direction perpendicular to the tape. Do not change the locations of any of your measurement lines.
6. Move the tape lines from the layer you moved them to in step one, back to the layer where the person model is to be found.

If you choose, before doing step 6, you can make a more accurate and detailed representation of the ends of your tape measure

Comment: thank you so much, but this sounds extremely complicated. all i really need is to draw a line, even if it is grease pencil just to indicate where the tape measure should be placed…or if it is a tape measure even better, but I do not need to show any measurements, its just instructing how to measure properly. is it possible for you to link a you tube video to point me in the right direction. thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a Youtube video on this.

Comment: Dear Basshat, I am slowly but surely following your instructions….thank you so much for your input I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: @michelle, you're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to draw a line on your model, the grease pencil should do alright.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=3lIX10qcPWk
8 minutes in shows how to draw on a surface.

You might need to toggle *X-ray* on-or-off to achieve your desired result.